# MongoDB filter Collections not contained in the array field of another colletion

Tags: mongodb

I need two queires for the collections bellow. The first one I think it's simpler, the second I'm not sure if it's even possible but would fit me better.

Workflow:

```
{"_id" 1:, "name": "Workflow 1": "connections": [1, 2]}
{"_id" 2:, "name": "Workflow 2": "connections": [3, 4]}
```

Connection:

```
{"_id": 1, "name": "Connection 1"}
{"_id": 2, "name": "Connection 2"}
{"_id": 3, "name": "Connection 3"}
{"_id": 4, "name": "Connection 4"}
{"_id": 5, "name": "Connection 5"}
{"_id": 6, "name": "Connection 6"}
```

## 1 - First query:

How can I filter my Connection collection to retrieve only the ones that are not inside Workflow 1,2?

In that case, the query should return:

```
{"_id": 5, "name": "Connection 5"}
{"_id": 6, "name": "Connection 6"}
```

## 2 - Second query:

How can I filter my Connection collection to retrieve only the ones that are not inside any Workflow? That is, in this case, I would not need to have the list of workflows for the query meaning connections that are not contained in any possible one.

The two queries would return the same result, but the second one I would not need to retrieve the list of workflows first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieve connection,

- `$lookup` to join `workflow` collection
- `$match` connection id in array or not
- `$match` is `connections` is not
- `$project` to show requried fields

```
db.connection.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "workflow",
      let: { c_id: "$_id" },
      as: "connections",
      pipeline: [ { $match: { $expr: { $in: ["$$c_id", "$connections"] } } } ]
    }
  },
  { $match: { connections: { $eq: [] } } },
  { $project: { _id: 1, name: 1 } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ihz6Rf2tmv3)

Comment: @Mauricio  not getting second query, i think its fulfilled in this single query.

Comment: Since you gave me the exact query that I need, I am checking as the correct answer. But it didn't work for my 10GB database since it turned out to be really heavy query.